# retrieve images from sql database and put it on datalist

Tags: mysql, asp.net, sql, sql-server

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" RepeatColumns = "2"  RepeatLayout = "Table"  Width = "500px">
<ItemTemplate>
    <br />
    <table cellpadding = "5px" cellspacing = "0" >
    <tr>
        <td>
          <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Photo") %>' Width = "200px" Height = "200px" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <br /> 
</ItemTemplate>
```

I have this datalist tag. I want to show pictures in 200x200 size and 3 pictures in a row. Images are to be fetched from sql database. Below is the detail of the table in which I am storing Images..

```
Table name ===> Photo

Photo_ID as int,
Photo as varbinary(MAX),
Content_Type as varchar(200)
```

What should I do to make it possible? How can I bind datalist so that it shows pictures to the user.?

Please help me

Comment: If you weren't storing your images in the DB, you'd just output the appropriate `<img src="/path/to/image.jpg" />`. But since you are, you can't.

Answer (score 0):

I shall suggest you 3 tutorials. They provide you the code and a very well explanation.

I hope these links can help you!

1. [Uploading / Downloading Pictures to / from a SQL Server](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8681/Uploading-Downloading-Pictures-to-from-a-SQL-Serve)
2. [Inserting and Retrieving images from SQL Server Database using C#](http://www.redmondpie.com/inserting-in-and-retrieving-image-from-sql-server-database-using-c/)
3. [Display images from SQL Server Database in ASP.Net](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Display-images-from-SQL-Server-Database-in-ASP.Net-GridView-control.aspx)